# How to add a pytorch model as a resource file to android app in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, opencv

I am using the DNN classifier and it requires a Mobilenet onnx file.
This is the source code for the project https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/DNN-OpenCV-Classification-with-Java/DnnOpenCV.java

I downloaded the model file from
https://github.com/onnx/models/tree/main/vision/classification/mobilenet/model

I would like to include it as a resource inside of my app so I can load it with

```
    Net dnnNet = Dnn.readNetFromONNX(MODEL_PATH);
```

Currently the add crashes on this line, eventhough the ONNX file is in the right location in my project folder, I cannot get it to deploy with my phone application to the emulator or to my phone.

Searching online I can only find answers on how to add XML resources, can I add binary or text files as well like this ONNX file?

How can I add this file as a resource so it loads with the application?
Looking for a detailed answer with every step as I am completely new to android studio and java

Comment: Why aren't you using: https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/tree/master/DNN-OpenCV-Classification-Android Alternatively there is: https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/tutorials/mobile/ otherwise most of the ML stuff for Android is [Tensorflow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/android/quickstart) based (different engine and model format).

Comment: I thought ONNX is universal format. Anyway I tried pytorch_mobilenet.onnx from the link you shared and I am getting SIGSEGV errors on the readNetFromONNX function. Can't find a solution, do you knpow if this is caused by some format error?

Comment: The code I am using is from the links you provided DNN-OpenCV-Classification-with-Java/DnnOpenCV.java

Comment: Found onnx in https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/tree/master/DNN-OpenCV-Classification-Android/img_classification_android/app/src/main/assets

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing. Android != Java SE != Linux. The Java project you linked to is for command line only. I linked to the Android version (see README.md for article). Just to confirm, I downloaded the learnopencv repo, imported the Android project into Android Studio, had to fix/change the JAVA SDK used, then built and ran the demo app on my physical device (Pixel 2 Android 10). As you state you are new to Android, you should go through recent tutorials (although most are now Kotlin orientated), the wiki at the bottom has resources: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info